# How should I upgrade Xcode after upgrading to OS X Lion?

Tags: xcode, upgrade, osx-lion, homebrew

I've just found out, that my homebrew doesn't work anymore after I upgraded to OS X Lion.

```
$ brew install clojure
Warning: Xcode is not installed! Builds may fail!
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/bin/cc
```

and

```
$ brew doctor
We couldn't detect gcc 4.2.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

We couldn't detect gcc 4.0.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

You have no /usr/bin/cc. This will cause numerous build issues. Please
reinstall Xcode.
Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH can break dynamic linking.
You should probably unset it.
```

after some googling, I found out that I should upgrade Xcode to version 4.1. The problem is, I have version 3.2.5 installed and I can't find any way of uninstalling it.

[image: Xcode]

When I look at App Store, it looks like I don't have Xcode installed at all. I'm afraid that if I install it via App Store, it will somehow conflict with the version I have currently installed. However I can't find it in Applications, and I can't find any update function either.

Software Update doesn't prompt me to update Xcode, and I also don't see it in Installed Software.

[image]

**What should I do?**

Comment: Xcode 4.0+ was launched around the same time as the Mac App Store, so unless you have this version or higher it won't show up as being associated with the store. You can get v4.2 for Lion via the store or grab the dmg of 4.2 for Snow Leopard by logging into your developer account. Is there anything in your Developer folder currently, as this is where Xcode is installed by default?

Comment: @Luke yes I have /Developer folder.

Comment: And what's inside it? Should either be nothing, the remnants of your old Xcode or a full install of a version of Xcode and the SDK.

Comment: I've got a full Xcode install, but I also found a readme, suggesting `$ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` for complete uninstall, so that should work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the readme found at `/Developer`, I found a way to uninstall Xcode via

```
$ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

**edit:** I just ran the installer for Xcode 4, and it detected old version of Xcode, offering me to move it to `/Developer-old`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by

In theory this should work if you have Xcode4.3 installed (in /Applications):

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```